# How to create a JSON feed for FullCalendar in a C# web application

Tags: c#, mysql, json, fullcalendar

I've found many articles online about using a JSON feed with FullCalendar. What I can't find is some basic understanding on the big picture.

I have a web application that loads user specific events from our database into the FullCalendar. Currently I query the database and pass everything to FullCalendar on startup. This is starting to take too long so I'm looking at other alternatives.

With the JSON feed, do I have a completely separate process that is always running on the server that contains the events for a specific user? How do you support multiple users that have user specific events that are to show on their calendar? Does the JSON feed get started when the user starts the web application from my C# code?

Comment: From what you've stated it's hard for me to say what is causing the slowness. You seem convinced it is in fact the amount of data being retrieved that is the issue but have you done any type of profiling on the application yet?

Comment: We've timed how long it takes to query our DB and build the data that we pass to the calendar so we know it's taking longer and longer over time because we are grabbing all the data from 2+ years back and 1+ years into the future (because we don't know where the user will go in their calendar). As I understand it, if we use a JSON feed that already has all that data before the user start our application, the calendar will only grab a single month of data from the feed, so that has to be a large improvement from what we are doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the JSON feed, do I have a completely separate process that is
>   always running on the server that contains the events for a specific
>   user?

- You do need something separate on a server, but it is not a process that is always running.  The way you specify the feed is in the fullCalendar events option you pass a URL rather than an array of events or a function.  When the calendar is first displayed and also each time the user navigates to a different time period fullCalendar will use ajax to do a get http request, and it will automatically add query parameters to the url for the start and end of the time period it needs to display.  So what you need to provide is anything that can be reached by a url and can return the event data for that time period.  This could be a web page that will execute the database query and return a JSON array of events rather than returning html as a web page normally would.  Some databases (I've done it with SQL/Anywhere) can implement a web service that you can reach directly via url to a specific port number on the database server and the web service can do the query as a stored procedure and return the result set in JSON format which eliminates the need for the intermediate web pages, but if your database cannot do this then making a small web page to act as an intermediary to the database is a good way to go.

> How do you support multiple users that have user specific events that
>   are to show on their calendar?

- I would suggest that you add another query parameter to the ajax request to your event feed and pass a userID whose events you want to display.  The second parameter in the events option after the url is "data:" and this is where you can add additional parameters to pass in the querystring of the url.  It can be a function.  See fullCalendar doc on event data for details.  Having passed the user ID, whatever is at the other end of your URL can use that user ID to retrieve only events for that user.  Of course the user ID has to be part of the event data stored in the database to be able to do this.

> Does the JSON feed get started when the user starts the web
>   application from my C# code?

- Not precisely.  It starts the first time the calendar is displayed; it returns the first batch of data needed for that display, and then it stops. Whenever the user moves to a different time period this happens again.  It runs on demand, each time fullCalendar issues a request for data.  It works just the way web servers (and databases) typically respond to requests.  Of course web servers and databases typically **are** running all the time in the background, but the particular web page or web service that supplies the event data is only run on demand by the web server and the database each time new data is needed.

Comment: Wow, that makes a whole lot more sense now. I think I can run with that and make this work. Thanks Keith

Comment: Great!  I'm glad it helped.  If this answer is satisfactory would you please click the checkmark next to it to mark it (or any other) as the accepted answer?  Thanks!